# bstheme with Shiny app not reflecting expected bootswatch theme

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, shiny

Below is a minimal reproducible example to show that I am using the bootswatch theme flatly and would think the components would automatically reflect the styling as shown on the preview page [here](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/). The navbar and submit buttons seem about right, but the other components do not reflect the styling.

Is there a class attribute I need to pass to things in shiny to get them to reflect a certain intended styling? For example, how might I get my action button to look like the "primary" as shown on the flatly preview page?

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage(
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly"),
    title = 'Methods',
    tabPanel('One'),
    tabPanel('Two'),
    tabPanel('Three'),
    tabPanel('Four')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h1('Hello World'),
    fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    actionButton('aButton', 'Do Stuff'),
    submitButton("Submit"),
    checkboxInput('aCheckBox', 'Check Me', TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT:
I have found that I can do the following

```
actionButton("primary", "Primary", class = "btn-primary m-2")
```

which achieves the styling I want in the example. I'll ask my question now in a different way, is there a way in which I can apply this globally across my shiny app so I don't need to style every single action button? My app is a very large application

Comment: Have you also looked at `shinythemes`? https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I've tried both. shinythemes seems to load much faster (at least locally), but it's the same issue. I can pass the class to one particular actionButton but would still need to apply them globally as far as I can tell

Comment: I have the same problem. I thought there would be an easy way to switch between primary color/dark and light color. Very silly if we need to update every single component